# How to disable temporary cursor with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Following my code:

HTML:

```
<div>test</div>
```

CSS:

```
div:hover{
background-color: black;
}
```

How to disable temporary cursor when the cursor is over (even ignoring :hover) the div and enter key is pressed and reenable when the cursor is moved with pure javascript?

Comment: You cannot. The OS controls the cursor. You can hide in Flash, possible in an HTML5 Canvas 2d/3d animation/video but not othwise...

Comment: `cursor:none` would hide the cursor but I don't think it is good UX.

Comment: :hover is still active after cursor:none...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could use CSS [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) which will stop all mouse events working, which includes `:hover`.

**CSS**

```
div:hover {
    background-color:black; /* will not happen */
}

div {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/SXyHV/)

Comment: This isn't supported in IE<=8, although I don't think we should worry about that any more.

Answer (score 0):

You can force specific cursor shapes with the CSS [cursor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor) attribute.

```
div {
    cursor: pointer; /* or any other shape available in the link above */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a transparent gif and use this code:

```
cursor: url("transparent.gif"), default;
```